# Unreachable Statement in Strings of Array

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.dennis.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        String[] forecastArray = {
        "Today - Sunny - 88 / 63",
        "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70 / 46",
        "Weds - Cloudy - 72 / 63",
        "Thurs - Rainy - 64 / 51",
        "Fri - Foggy - 70 / 46",
        "Sat - Sunny - 76 / 68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on creating `ArrayList` on **IDE** but I stumble upon an error shows at String[] forecastArray = ..... }; saying that **'Unreachable Statement'**.

Answer (score 5):

Your method will end on this line (notice the `return` statement):

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Anything after that line is unreachable, in other words, can never execute.

Answer (score 1):

After return statement method is returned so no other code is executed after return statement .

Try to move your logic before return .

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] forecastArray = {
        "Today - Sunny - 88 / 63",
        "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70 / 46",
        "Weds - Cloudy - 72 / 63",
        "Thurs - Rainy - 64 / 51",
        "Fri - Foggy - 70 / 46",
        "Sat - Sunny - 76 / 68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

 }
```